# tkinter label is not showing output OOP

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

Hi guys I need your help with my code , so I am trying to practice OOP in python and I am creating tkinter GUI that updates the label so the label should show the percentage.
I import 'resut' from another python file. i dont have problem with the result parameter because its showing correctly in terminal . but my problem is i cant make it show in the tkinter label see codes below. i tried to put the method above but it needs the parameter what I am trying to produce is to show the score as percentage in tkinter label because the result contains the score for detection so i convert it to percentage first then I want to show it on the label.

```
class interface(tk.Tk):
        
 def __init__(self):
  super().__init__()
  self.geometry('500x500')
  self.result_val
  
  

 def result_val(self, result):
         
        
         
    classification = result.classifications[0]
    label_list = [
        category.category_name for category in classification.categories
    ]
    score_list = [category.score for category in classification.categories]
    
   
    for num in score_list:
        percentage = "{:.0%}".format(num)      
        
        
    self.label = tk.Label(self, text =percentage)
    self.label.pack() 
  
  
  
inter = interface()
inter.mainloop()
```

result is a local variable from another python file

this is the function of the result

```
def run(model: str, max_results: int, score_threshold: float,
        overlapping_factor: float, num_threads: int,
        enable_edgetpu: bool) -> None:
  """Continuously run inference on audio data acquired from the device.

  Args:
    model: Name of the TFLite audio classification model.
    max_results: Maximum number of classification results to display.
    score_threshold: The score threshold of classification results.
    overlapping_factor: Target overlapping between adjacent inferences.
    num_threads: Number of CPU threads to run the model.
    enable_edgetpu: Whether to run the model on EdgeTPU.
  """

  if (overlapping_factor <= 0) or (overlapping_factor >= 1.0):
    raise ValueError('Overlapping factor must be between 0 and 1.')

  if (score_threshold < 0) or (score_threshold > 1.0):
    raise ValueError('Score threshold must be between (inclusive) 0 and 1.')

  # Initialize the audio classification model.
  base_options = core.BaseOptions(
      file_name=model, use_coral=enable_edgetpu, num_threads=num_threads)
  classification_options = processor.ClassificationOptions(
      max_results=max_results, score_threshold=score_threshold)
  options = audio.AudioClassifierOptions(
      base_options=base_options, classification_options=classification_options)
  classifier = audio.AudioClassifier.create_from_options(options)

  # Initialize the audio recorder and a tensor to store the audio input.
  audio_record = classifier.create_audio_record()
  tensor_audio = classifier.create_input_tensor_audio()

  # We'll try to run inference every interval_between_inference seconds.
  # This is usually half of the model's input length to create an overlapping
  # between incoming audio segments to improve classification accuracy.
  input_length_in_second = float(len(
      tensor_audio.buffer)) / tensor_audio.format.sample_rate
  interval_between_inference = input_length_in_second * (1 - overlapping_factor)
  pause_time = interval_between_inference * 0.1
  last_inference_time = time.time()

  # Initialize a plotter instance to display the classification results.
  ui_val = graphic_ui
  
  # Initialize log file to store the classification results.
  log_file = open("classification_log.txt", "w")
  
  # Start audio recording in the background.
  audio_record.start_recording()

  # Loop until the user close the classification results plot.
  while True:
    # Wait until at least interval_between_inference seconds has passed since
    # the last inference.
    now = time.time()
    diff = now - last_inference_time
    if diff < interval_between_inference:
      time.sleep(pause_time)
      continue
    last_inference_time = now

    # Load the input audio and run classify.
    tensor_audio.load_from_audio_record(audio_record)
    result = classifier.classify(tensor_audio)

    # Write the classification results to the log file.
    time_stamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
    category = result.classifications[0].categories[0]
    score = category.score * 100
    log_file.write("{}, {}, {:.2f}%\n".format(time_stamp, category.category_name, score))
    
    # Plot the classification results.
    ui_val(result)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.   Where are you importing result in your code?  The method in question is never even called.  please create a [mre]

Comment: `self.result_val` is a statement that does nothing.  It's like writing `7`.  You need `self.result_val()` to have the function get called.

Comment: @TimRoberts i tried that self.result_val() but i need to put something to that because result is the parameter of the method result_val what I am trying to produce is to show the score as percentage in tkinter label because the result contains the score for detection so i convert it to percentage first then I want to show it on the label.

Comment: Well, you can't call `result_val` in the constructor, because you don't have the result yet.  Right?  How are you going to run the `run` function?  I don't see that here.